# Cross assembly Attributes in prism

Tags: c#, prism, .net-assembly, custom-attributes

I wrote a custom attribute which I used in a module "**DomainModule**",
The Attribute uses a helper class in a referenced assembly **"Assembly A"**
The Attribute definition is there:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class RidTabAttribute : Attribute
```

And the **Helper Class "Assembly A"** uses **"Assembly B"** or here: `Zepers.Ribb`
Which brings the information and resources to the module view.

I'm given an error mentioned below,
please tell me how can I fix this.

**Error Line : (In Domain Module)**

```
return type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), true).OfType<T>();
```

**Error Outline:**

```
{"Could not load file or assembly 'Zelopers.Ribb, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Zelopers.Ribb, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"}
```

**StackTrace :**

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Zelopers.Ribb, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' 
or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute._CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule pModule, IRuntimeMethodInfo pCtor, Byte** ppBlob, Byte* pEndBlob, Int32* pcNamedArgs)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule module, IRuntimeMethodInfo ctor, IntPtr& blob, IntPtr blobEnd, Int32& namedArgs)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
   at Zelopers.Prism.RibbonHelper.XamRibbonRegionBehavior.GetCustomAttributes[T](Type type) in e:\Wyrocco\ProjectsHall\Xz\Inside\Src\Common\Zepers.RibbonHelper\XamRibbonRegionBehavior.cs:line 58
   at Zelopers.Prism.RibbonHelper.XamRibbonRegionBehavior.ActiveViews_CollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) in e:\Wyrocco\ProjectsHall\Xz\Inside\Src\Common\Zelopers.RibbonHelper\XamRibbonRegionBehavior.cs:line 40
   at System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.ViewsCollection.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.ViewsCollection.NotifyAdd(IList items, Int32 newStartingIndex)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.ViewsCollection.NotifyAdd(Object item)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.ViewsCollection.OnItemMetadataChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.ItemMetadata.InvokeMetadataChanged()
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.ItemMetadata.DependencyPropertyChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.Region.Activate(Object view)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.SingleActiveRegion.Activate(Object view)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.ContentControlRegionAdapter.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Adapt>b__1(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.ViewsCollection.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.ViewsCollection.NotifyAdd(IList items, Int32 newStartingIndex)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.ViewsCollection.NotifyAdd(Object item)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.ViewsCollection.SourceCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.InsertItem(Int32 index, T item)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Add(T item)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.Region.InnerAdd(Object view, String viewName, IRegionManager scopedRegionManager)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.Region.Add(Object view, String viewName, Boolean createRegionManagerScope)
   at...Common\Zepers.Prism\Base\ModuleBase.cs:line 42
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleInitializer.Initialize(ModuleInfo moduleInfo)
```

**Error Location in the Error Message Box :**

```
   {System.Object _CreateCaObject(System.Reflection.RuntimeModule, System.IRuntimeMethodInfo, Byte**, Byte*, Int32*)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project where you are calling the following line,

```
return type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), true).OfType<T>();
```

add `Zelopers.Ribb` as a reference.

Comment: Do you also have it where the call started, at code section where you are using Initialize of ModuleInitializer?

Comment: Seems you should be right, didn't think it could be that easy, Was expecting a reflection answer to load and inject ! The Shell(Main) Assembly didn't have a reference to it, and may be that could be the answer, I still have some errors, cause moved some pieces across the projects, and can't be sure yet this could be the final answer, anyway to me seems correct, let me try, Thanks +1s

Comment: in fact if you are employing IOC, you need to reference all objects resolved using IOC in the project where the resolution of the tree starts.